# How does one prove atoms in propositional logic?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I was going through the completeness theorem for propositional logic from [these notes](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~vddries/main.pdf) (on page 23 Lemma 2.2.12). Before the proof they give a crucial definition:

$$
t_{\Sigma}(a) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  1  & \mbox{if } \Sigma \vdash a \\
  0 & \mbox{if } \Sigma \not \vdash a
 \end{array}
\right.
$$

which felt like a rather unsatisfactory definition of a truth function and I wanted to figure out why. I think the pain reason I thought it was odd was because in my head one can't "prove the atoms". The atoms are just statements, say about the world like a="The clouds are white" which are considered of length 1 and that are either true of false. What I mean they are true or false is that if we had $n$ atoms then setting them to true or false would correspond to one row of a truth table, namely $\{ 0,1\}^n$. Thus a truth function $t:A \to \{0,1\}$ can be thought as a row of the truth table (that then induces truths on propositions). However, here we are defining truth w.r.t. to provability which seems odd to me. So my questions are:

1. what does it mean to "prove an atom"? I know what formal proof means, its a sequence of statements that are either propositional axioms, are in $\Sigma$ or arrived via Modus Ponens (MP). However, how can one arrive at any atom $a$? Wouldn't that be possible IFF the atoms were already included in $\Sigma$?
2. $\Sigma \not \vdash a$ seems even harder to show is true. i.e. how do we show there is no smart way of combining the logical rules to never arrive at $a$? My intuition tells me that this can be showed for atoms IFF they are not in $a$ in which $\Sigma \vdash a$ is just a short hand for inclusion of sets.

So is this function $t_{\Sigma}(a)$ just an indicator function if the current atom (statement) is in our set of assumptions $\Sigma$? I guess that would make sense as a way to define truth, we only consider things true if they are in our set of assumptions. Is this correct? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can one arrive at any atom $a$? Wouldn't that be possible IFF the atoms were already included in Σ?

No. The set $\Sigma$, which is an arbitrary subset of $\text{Prop}(A)$, might well include $a\land b$ but not $a$; nevertheless $\Sigma\vdash a$.

---

**Added**. Here's some more context. The set $\Sigma$ here stands for a propositional "theory": it models (I mean the word in an informal sense, not the technical logical sense) a set of assumptions or axioms (in the informal sense, not the axioms that go into your axiomatic proof system) you'd like to make about a domain of discourse.

Some books define a *theory* to be not just a subset of well-formed formulas in the grammar of propositional or predicate logic, but the *syntactic closure* of a set of well-formed formulas. If you only allow yourself to write $T\vdash p$ where $T$ is a theory in the second, stronger sense, then $p\in T$ after all. But if you allow yourself to write $T\vdash p$ where $T$ is a theory in the first, weaker sense, it does not follow that $p\in T$.

Comment: how do you prove an atom if its not in the theory/model/assumptions $\Sigma$?

Comment: I just gave you an example: did you not read the top of my answer? Suppose $\Sigma$ contains only $a\land b$. Then you can prove $a$ using axiom schema 4 in your notes, together with modus ponens.

Comment: I think something that is crucially confusing me is that if $\Sigma \not \vdash a$, if that means that $\Sigma \vdash \neg a$

Comment: Certainly not. If $\Sigma$ is the empty set, then $\Sigma$ proves neither $a$ nor $\lnot a$. Only theories that are “negation complete” have the property you described.

Comment: yes thats what I thought. However notice the definition of $t_{\Sigma}(a)$. If we have $\Sigma \not \vdash a \implies t_{\Sigma}(a) = 0$. Then we can conclude $t_{\Sigma}(\neg a) = 1$ because $ t_{\Sigma}(\neg a) = 1 - t_{\Sigma}(a) = 1 - 0 = 1$. But if you look at the definition of $t_{\Sigma}(a)$ that implies $\Sigma \vdash \neg a$. Which doesn't seem legit because we concluded something about provability through an artificial definition rather than actually proving it (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2952038/why-is-the-truth-function-t-sigmap-that-picks-up-provable-proposition-leg)

Comment: I guess I am trying to understand what the deal is with non provability in propositional logic and propositional logic only. I always thought that statements in propositional logic were always decidable because we could brute force the values of all truth function in the atoms...though I feel I'm not connecting the dots somewhere...

Comment: “Then we can conclude ...” No. The function $t_\Sigma$ is not a semantic interpretation $t$. It is true that if $t$ is an interpretation function then $t(\lnot a)=1-t(a)$. But $t_\Sigma$ is just an indicator of whether or not $\Sigma$ proves $a$.

Comment: If $t_{\Sigma}(\neg a) = 1$ then $t(a) = 0$ so we magically know $\Sigma \not \vdash a$. Where exactly is the mistake in the logic?

Comment: It is possible that both $\Sigma\nvdash a$ and $\Sigma\nvdash\neg a$.  In such a case then $t_\Sigma(\neg a)=0$ and $t_\Sigma(a)=0$ and so $t_\Sigma(\neg a)\neq 1-t_\Sigma(a)$.  Likewise if $\Sigma$ is inconsistent, then $\Sigma\vdash a$ and $\Sigma\vdash\neg a$ so $t_\Sigma(\neg a)=1$, $t_\Sigma(a)=1$ and so $t_\Sigma(\neg a)\neq 1-t_\Sigma(a)$ too.